# Draw rectangle(s) in Objective-C for iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in Objective C and I want to draw a rectangle on the iPhone screen.

What I have done is:

-Create a new Class called CustomView

-Adapt the AppDelegate.m file as follows:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
CGRect bigRect =  CGRectMake (100, 100, 100, 100) ;
CGRect smallRect =  CGRectMake (50, 50, 50, 50);
CustomView * bigView = [[ CustomView alloc ]  initWithFrame:bigRect ];
CustomView * smallView = [[ CustomView alloc ]  initWithFrame:smallRect ];
[ bigView setBackgroundColor :[ UIColor redColor ]];
[ smallView setBackgroundColor :[ UIColor blueColor ]];
[ self.window addSubview:bigView ];
[ self.window addSubview:smallView ];

return YES;
```

}

When I simulate this I only get a white screen. I suspect that I might need to update the class CustomView itself?

Answer (score 0):

Why use appDelegate? You need to add methods to create user interface in ViewController implementation.

Please try simplier solution:

```
-(void)drawBox
    UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 35, 10, 10)];
    myBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myBox];
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad call that method. Parameters of `CGRectMake` is x,y, height and width, you may want to edit it depending on your needs.

I also recommend to check this article - https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwj0-vXRz4PJAhWCjiwKHd36Bo0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUIView_Class%2F&usg=AFQjCNHj3LrxW69BtP-2db5kevpbQ_AuKw&sig2=LTnzngT5im-5Jr8wWNeqbQ&cad=rjt

Comment: Tahnk you for your answer. As I said before I just started with Objective-C, so I still have some trouble getting around. To call this method I need to pass an parameter, what should it be? [self drawRect: ?]

Comment: @MucMax i will edit my answer in couple of minutes. If solution will work, please provide answer as correct, clicking checkmark button from left pane.